# ad mob policy issue

Tags: android-studio, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Im getting this issue can someone solve this by looking the code
Disallowed Rewarded Implementation Must fix Rewarded ads may only be served after a user affirmatively opts to view a rewarded ad. Additionally, a user must opt to view each rewarded ad individually and cannot opt-in to automatically seeing rewarded ads.

this is the code where ads are initilized

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class comp extends AppCompatActivity {

```
compAdapter compAdapter1;
RewardedAd rewardedAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_afl);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.trans));
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            int statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    Button back = findViewById(R.id.backm);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(comp.this, notesss.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });



    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedYear = sharedPreferences.getInt("selectedYear", 0); // 0 is the default value if the key is not found

    if (selectedYear == 1) {
        loadADS();
        RecyclerView EErec = findViewById(R.id.aflN);
        EErec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<compM> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<compM>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("firstYr").child("nanosc")
                                , compM.class)
                        .build();
        compAdapter1 = new compAdapter(options, new BtnClick() {
            @Override
            public void btnClick(String open) {
                showADS(open);
            }
        });
        EErec.setAdapter(compAdapter1);
    }
    else if (selectedYear == 2) {
        loadADS();
        RecyclerView EErec = findViewById(R.id.aflN);
        EErec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<compM> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<compM>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("secondYr").child("compA")
                                , compM.class)
                        .build();
        compAdapter1 = new compAdapter(options, new BtnClick() {
            @Override
            public void btnClick(String open) {
                showADS(open);
            }
        });
        EErec.setAdapter(compAdapter1);
    } else if (selectedYear == 3) {
        loadADS();
        RecyclerView EErec = findViewById(R.id.aflN);
        EErec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<compM> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<compM>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("thirdYr").child("spm")
                                , compM.class)
                        .build();
        compAdapter1 = new compAdapter(options, new BtnClick() {
            @Override
            public void btnClick(String open) {
                showADS(open);
            }
        });
        EErec.setAdapter(compAdapter1);
    }
}
private void showADS(String open) {
    boolean userOptedIn = true; // Set this value based on user action.

    if (userOptedIn) {
        if (rewardedAd != null) {
            Activity activityContext = this;
            rewardedAd.show(activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                    openLink(open);
                    // Load the next rewarded ad after the user has earned the reward.
                    loadADS();
                }
            });
            rewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                    rewardedAd = null;
                    openLink(open);
                    // Load the next rewarded ad after the current ad is dismissed.
                    loadADS();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                    Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
                    rewardedAd = null;
                    openLink(open);
                    // Load the next rewarded ad after the current ad failed to show.
                    loadADS();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // If the rewarded ad is not loaded, display the content without showing the ad.
            Toast.makeText(comp.this, "opening..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            openLink(open);
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case when the user has not opted to watch a rewarded ad.
        // Optionally, you can display a message or take other actions.
        openLink(open);
    }
}


private void openLink(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void loadADS() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    String rewardedAdId = getString(R.string.ads);
    RewardedAd.load(comp.this, rewardedAdId, adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd ad) {
            rewardedAd = ad;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    compAdapter1.startListening();
}
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

}